# Is it possible to use the page scrollbar to scroll an inner div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has a fixed height and a scrollable div inside that. Is it possible to remove the inner scrollbar and change it to the pages' one? The current example with the scrollbar inside the div is [here](http://fem.dreamhosters.com/?p=4).

I suspect this might need to be done with Javascript and a search on Stack Overflow shows a number of entries referring to it but I'm kind of hoping it doesn't need to be done using Javascript.

Currently, I just let the users scroll inside the div but it's not really an elegant solution:

```
.singlepost {
position: fixed;
top: 270px;
bottom: 20px;
background-color: white;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: While doable, it's not going to make sense to the user. One expects the page scrollbar to scroll the page, and only the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the browser's scrollbar"?  This is a kinda strange question, so would you please provide, in as much detail as possible, exactly what you want to happen.  e.g., "When the user does FOO I want BAR to happen, and when they reach BAZ, and their mouse is BAP, I want BOO to happen, until condition FAA..."

Comment: so do you want the pictures and the navbar to stay put, and only the white part to move? like Matt said, most users will be confused by that.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't think of a very good way to explain this. I want the default browser page scrollbar (on the right of the browser) to become the scrollbar for the inner div on the page. I only want the white part of the page to scroll.

Comment: I think you're right though, it could be a poor user experience, but so could scrolling accidentally on the black div and expecting it to scroll the main content in the white div.

Answer (score 2):

You could set every other element on the page to `position: fixed`, leaving your div to expand the body and make it scrollable. Check the fiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/TnzG5/4/

[The Next Web](http://thenextweb.com) uses a similar tactic.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your demo page, it may be easiest to just put everything above into a div, which floats on top and whatever goes below scrolls up beneath the top div. That would keep your nav at the top and the rest of the page scrolling as usual, using the main windows scrollbar.